# Simple PHP image gallery with file upload

Tags: php, image-gallery

I am looking for a really simple PHP image gallery system that allows file uploads and provides easy integration into any existing PHP script. I only found full galleries with database backend and templating systems for integration and the too simple ones that just take a folder with (FTP uploaded) images and show it but don't provide the possibilities for file uploads.

I'm quite close on writing my own, cause I didn't find anything yet, but I first wanted to ask if you have any suggestions.

Comment: If you're any good, you're probably better off writing your own.  It's not hard to support uploads, add a little jQuery, and make things look nice.

Comment: question: why would you not want to use a database for this?? mySQL is not too hard to use, and you can always use SQLlite for flat files...

Comment: Because there was simply no need to. A database just adds complexity (no matter how easy it is to use) where it is not required. My gallery will have an optional database plugin soon though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I have a very early version of it [on Github](http://github.com/daffl/gally), it is under development (and not really nice yet, I just needed the admin interface up and running) but contributions and comments are welcome.